# Using a bridge br0 while using eth0 and eth0:1

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

My Situation:

I have a Server with Ubuntu 16.04 running on it.

This Server has 2 IP Adresses.

Now I wanted to install a Brige to give a VM (KVM) acces to the Network so i dont have to write endless IP tabels rules for that portforwarding.

Is there any way to do?

If i enter a bridge and then type "brctl show" it won't who up my recelty created br0.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ethX device for your bridge to manual in the `/etc/network/interfaces` and assgine the bridge port the the ethX device. e.g.:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 5
```

Now you can use the `br0` device in KVM or virsh.

```
sudo brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.5254003fa659       no              eth0
```

See https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections for more details on bridge devices.

As always, you can add multible IP addresses to any device e.g.:

```
auto br0:1
iface br0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: But where do i define my two ip adresses then?

Comment: @DaNeubi I updated my Answer